# Vercel: serverless timeout function for fetch mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, serverless, vercel

i've made a simple website in nextjs with some data stored in a mongodb atlas...

i deploy it on vercel and the app at loading shows the error:

> This Serverless Function has timed out.

i see on other post that the hobby plan has 10s for each serverless function...

there's something i can do to reduce time of fetch or split the function in more part with lower time?

below the function

> server/db_connection.ts

```
    import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI!;

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});

export async function dbConnection() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  } catch (err) {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    console.error(err);
  }
}
dbConnection();

export default async function clientPromise(){
  const db = client.db("Portfoilio")
  return db;
}
```

> server/project.ts

```
   import clientPromise, { dbConnection } from "../db/db_connection";

dbConnection();

export interface ProjectType {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    subtitle: string;
    link: string;
    github: string;
    skills: string[]
    images: {
        url: string;
        alt: string;
    }[];
}

export async function getProjects() {
    const client = await clientPromise();
    const projects = await client.collection('ProjectsData').find({}).toArray();

    const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projects));
    return jsonData;
}
```

> index.tsx

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  
    const favSkills = await getSkills();
    const projects = await getProjects();

    return {
      props: {
        favSkills,
        projects,
      },
    }
}
```

Tanks to everyone!